# tensorflow.py_function fails to temporarily switch to eager execution while in graph mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, eager-execution

I'm not sure if this is a Tensorflow bug or my misunderstanding about what this function is supposed to do, but I can't get `tf.py_function` to return an `EagerTensor` *while in graph mode*. Consequently, calling `.numpy()` on the output of this function fails.

The issue can be reproduced using the exact example given in the official documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function):

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

def log_huber(x, m):
  if tf.abs(x) <= m:
    return x**2
  else:
    return m**2 * (1 - 2 * tf.math.log(m) + tf.math.log(x**2))

x = tf.constant(1.0)
m = tf.constant(2.0)

with tf.GradientTape() as t:
  t.watch([x, m])
  y = tf.py_function(func=log_huber, inp=[x, m], Tout=tf.float32)

dy_dx = t.gradient(y, x)
assert dy_dx.numpy() == 2.0
```

This generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 446, in __getattr__
    self.__getattribute__(name)
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

#### About version

I am running Python 3.8 and Tensorflow v2.9.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

##### Solution 1 (with eager execution):

In Tensorflow 2, eager execution should be enabled by default.

I reproduced the exact same code as the Tensorflow tutorial without any problem (the assertion does not generate errors). I used Colab under Tensorflow 2.8.2 and Python 3.7.13.

If you have problems you could try setting `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)`, but really it should work even without this stuff.

##### Solution 2 (without eager execution):

If you want to keep eager execution disabled, you can work with sessions (more info about [sessions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Session)). Instead of calling `.numpy()` you should call `.eval()` on your Tensor and wrap everything in a session. That's it.

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

def log_huber(x, m):
  if tf.abs(x) <= m:
    return x**2
  else:
    return m**2 * (1 - 2 * tf.math.log(m) + tf.math.log(x**2))

x = tf.constant(1.0)
m = tf.constant(2.0)

# Launch the graph in a session.
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

with tf.GradientTape() as t:
  t.watch([x, m])
  y = tf.py_function(func=log_huber, inp=[x, m], Tout=tf.float32)

with sess.as_default():
  dy_dx = t.gradient(y, x)
  assert dy_dx.eval() == 2.0
  print(dy_dx.eval())

sess.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my question is about getting it to run with eager execution *disabled*. Sorry if this wasn't clear in the initial post. If you copy-paste the example from the tensorflow docs without adding tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution(), it runs fine, of course. But the point of py_function is to execute a function eagerly while in graph mode.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I misunderstood. You should be able to execute without eager mode with the second solution. I updated the answer @42bsk

Comment: No problem, and thanks again! Unfortunately eval() does not work for my problem, which is a whole other story and I'll save that for a different post... So, are you saying that tf.py_function does not execute eagerly when eager execution is disabled? I thought that was the whole point of the function: from the doc: "Wraps a python function into a TensorFlow op that executes it eagerly." Have I misunderstood what this means?

Comment: @42bsk I think that `tf.py_function` only executes the wrapped code, that is the code  inside, eagerly. This allows to use Python constructs inside, but not on the output of the wrapped function

Comment: I upvoted your answer since I appreciate anyone trying to help, but unfortunately this did not solve my issue. I tried moving all non-tensorflow code inside the py_function wrapper, including printing/saving intermediate output to a file, but when global eager execution is disabled, the non-tensorflow code is simply skipped and not executed at all. Despite what is written in the docs -- "You can also use tf.py_function to debug your models at runtime using Python tools" -- breakpoints inside the wrapped function are also skipped when eager execution is disabled.